# New to Sharepoint

Tags: books, guidance, learning, learning-kit

Being new to sharepoint, and there being an urgency in my learning the technology quickly, where is the best place to start... Books to buy, sites to research from etc not sure whats out there? I know i have around a fortnight before i am looking to pass the 70-667 exam (Yeah right, before i ask to take it again).

EDIT: Also, does anyone have any idea why the 70-667 exam has been out for so long yet the training kit still is not?

Comment: TechNet's the only resource you'll ever need as an admin ;)

Comment: Also, just had a look at your profile - if your company wants Gold Partner status I think you need to be an MCITP SharePoint Administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft offers a "Second Shot" retest option for certification exams.  Specifically, if you pay around 15% more for the first exam, you get a voucher that will let you retake it again at a later date if you do not pass the first try.

Also, if you are working for a Microsoft Partner then your company has access to the Partner Learning Center which include a large library of training sessions, demos and more.  It is definitely worth looking into.

Comment: Ass much as i would like to i cannot accept all three answers. All three have been really helpful and if i had the reputation i would indeed vote them all up. I was delivered a selection of books at work today, i will definitely be making use of TechNet and hope cramming like never before for what is now a a little over a week. Really useful to know i can look into what the company should get with their partner status, and i will definitely get the second shot as i can't imagine what i can do to pass this at such short notice.

Thanks very much guys, all very helpful... [Goes away to study]

Answer (score 1):

The exam hasn't been out that long in comparison to other Microsoft certs (less than one year since the Beta exams came out).

Best thing to do is to read this page: http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-667#tab2 Then look up the Skills Measured on TechNet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/default

Answer (score 1):

Sign up for a cloud trial instance of SharePoint. Then, watch the Lynda guide. http://www.lynda.com/SharePoint-2010-tutorials/essential-training/65720-2.html This will teach you what a working instance of SharePoint is *for*... yes that does take a couple of days or so of full-time learning. It's important to know this before you try to set it up, otherwise you'll be completely lost.

Chuck the could trial instance and start reading Microsoft Press SharePoint Administrator's Companion book. When you feel comfortable, start to build your own environment in VMs. You'll probably want a TechNet subscription to get all the software (or use trials - *don't* use foundation), and you'll need a 4 core machine with 8GB RAM and 200GB free space, *minimum*. 3 Tier architecture.

To be honest, I think you'd have to be already pretty knowledgable to pass this with only 2 weeks prep time. I would recommend skimming the companion book first, reading a few random pages in depth, and getting a feel for the complexity of the system. That'll give you a good idea on whether you should just give up now or not...

Comment: I'm glad giving up isn't actually an option, i have some hardware that i am going to use in the office, hopefully cluster a couple of sharepoint VM's and play with those. I have some exam practices that were donated by someone else so i already know the kind of questions that are going to be asked, what i intend to do is learn to pass the exam, not learn sharepoint in the next 2 weeks. Then i can go back and learn everything to keep me happy, and hopefully have a useless piece of paper to keep the boss happy (no doubt used to exploit my innocence later).

Comment: Looked at the technet Sub's, cost around £130, do you know what you get for that?